# How to make a cell highlight red if its less than 6 digits and NOT effect blank cells?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I use this function

```
=LEN(P3:P)<6
```

in order to highlight all the entries with less than 6 digits (6 is minimum)

However, all the blank cells also highlight red. What function do I have to do in order to not affect blank cells? I can base it on if Column E is filled (since that should always have info). But I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall use this custom formula:

```
=(LEN(P3)<6)*(P3<>"")
```

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly!